# Flutter: Display all users from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display all the users of my firestore database as a list (trying to develop a chat interface feature), [displaying the device status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kjOV.png)
Is there any package in flutter which can be called to make a chat interface?

below I have tried till now:

chat_interface.dart

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/header.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class Chats extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatUserId;
  Chats({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState(
    chatUserId:this.chatUserId,
  );
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chats> {

  TextEditingController chatController = TextEditingController();

  Future<QuerySnapshot> chatUsers = usersRef.getDocuments();

  final String chatUserId;
  _ChatState({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    userDisplay();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  }
  userDisplay(){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: chatUsers,
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<ChatResult> results = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){
        User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
        ChatResult result = ChatResult(user);
        results.add(result);
        });
        return ListView(
            children: results,
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

class ChatResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ChatResult(this.user);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, titleText: 'GupShup'),
      body: Container(
      color:Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
              ),
              title: Text(user.displayName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              subtitle: Text('Message'),
              ),
          Divider(
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.white54,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Chats(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme,
_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#4c382]], state: _ChatState#e9c68):
A build function returned null.
The offending widget is:
  Chats
Build functions must never return null.
To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
"Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
"Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Chats
[38;5;248m  [39;49m
 lib\widgets\header.dart
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[38;5;244m#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure>[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart
[38;5;244m#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart
[38;5;244m#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#4      Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#5      StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#6      Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#8      Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#9      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#10     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#11     StatelessElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#12     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#13     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#14     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#16     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#17     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#18     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#19     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#20     StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#21     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#23     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#25     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#26     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#27     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#28     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#29     StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#30     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#31     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#32     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#33     StatelessElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#34     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#35     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#36     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#37     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#38     StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#39     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#40     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#41     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#43     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#44     ProxyElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#45     _InheritedNotifierElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart
[38;5;244m#46     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#47     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#48     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#49     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#50     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#51     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#52     StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#53     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#54     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#55     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#56     ProxyElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#57     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#58     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#59     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#60     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#61     StatefulElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#62     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#63     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#64     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#65     StatelessElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#66     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#67     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#68     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#69     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#70     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#71     ProxyElement.update[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#72     Element.updateChild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#74     StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#75     Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#76     BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#77     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart
[38;5;244m#78     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart
[38;5;244m#79     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart
[38;5;244m#80     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart
[38;5;244m#81     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure>[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

[38;5;248m════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════[39;49m
[38;5;244mThe following assertion was thrown building Chats(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#4c382]], state: _ChatState#e9c68):[39;49m
A build function returned null.

[38;5;244mThe offending widget is: Chats[39;49m
[38;5;244mBuild functions must never return null.[39;49m

[38;5;248mTo return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".[39;49m

[38;5;244mThe relevant error-causing widget was[39;49m
    [38;5;248mChats[39;49m 
 lib\widgets\header.dart
[38;5;244mWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack[39;49m
[38;5;244m#0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure>[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart
[38;5;244m#1      debugWidgetBuilderValue[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/debug.dart
[38;5;244m#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m#4      Element.rebuild[39;49m 
 package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart
[38;5;244m...[39;49m
[38;5;248m════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════[39;49m
Reloaded 0 of 1172 libraries in 197ms.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I think I am unable to call the methods properly.

Edit: I have changed my code a little bit

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/header.dart';
import 'package:fluttershare/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'home.dart';

class Chats extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatUserId;
  Chats({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState(
    chatUserId:this.chatUserId,
  );
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chats> {

  TextEditingController chatController = TextEditingController();

  Future<QuerySnapshot> chatUsers = usersRef.document(currentUser.id).collection('users').limit(100).getDocuments();

  final String chatUserId;
  _ChatState({this.chatUserId});
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    userDisplay();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: header(context,titleText: 'GupShup'),
      body: chatUsers != null ?  userDisplay() : Text('Users'),
    );
  }
  userDisplay(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: usersRef.document(widget.chatUserId).collection('users').snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return circularProgress();
        }
        List<ChatResult> results = [];
        snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc){
        User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
        ChatResult result = ChatResult(user);
        results.add(result);
        });
        return ListView(
            children: results,
        );
      }
    );
  }
}

class ChatResult extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  ChatResult(this.user);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color:Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('show message'),
            child:
            ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
              ),
              title: Text(user.displayName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              subtitle: Text('Message'),
              ),
           ),
          Divider(
            height: 2.0,
            color: Colors.white54,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now I am getting a blank screen with the appBar

[After Edit the emulator shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OLjX.png)

Can anyone help me now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the widget from the build method

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return FutureBuilder(...);
  }
```

Comment: I have changed my code a little, can you have a look?